# Как узнать позицию каждого повторяющегося символа в строке?

Tags: python

> Дана строка. Замените в этой строке все появления буквы h на букву H, кроме второго и последнего вхождения.

Для решения задачи мне необходимо узнать позицию каждого повторения символа в строке.

Comment: А разве Вы не будете знать позицию при простом цикле по символам строки?

Answer (score 1):

Найти все индексы можно так

```
text='help hero of honor to hire hobbit'
indexes = []
i = -1
while True:
    try:
        i = text.index('h', i+1)
        indexes.append(i)
    except ValueError:
        break
```